# Authenticate header in Zend Soap Server using PHP

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, soap, soapserver

I am trying to authenticate soap header, when client send a request to the server. I need to do it by reading the soap header. I can set parameters to soap header but I don't know how to read soap header from server side and authenticate the client's request. Pls need a help.

Thank you.